# Splitting a list of strings into a dataframe at speed

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a Large list object (around 200,000 lines) with the structure of:

```
x1 <- "1614689:-1,1,-1,-826,-3484,0.00;-1,2,-1,-311,-3450,0.00;-1,3,-1,-3732,-708,0.00;-1,4,-1,137,-3387,0.00;4,5,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,6,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,7,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,8,-1,5550,4400,0.00;-1,9,-1,-1971,-2660,0.00;4,10,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,11,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,12,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,13,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,14,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,15,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,16,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,17,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,18,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,19,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,20,-1,5550,4400,0.00;-1,21,-1,401,-969,0.00;4,22,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,23,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,24,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,25,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,26,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,27,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,28,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,29,-1,5550,4400,0.00;:-1971,-2660,0,6.08,A,Dead;"

x2 <- "1614690:-1,1,-1,-825,-3484,0.00;-1,2,-1,-311,-3450,0.00;-1,3,-1,-3726,-706,0.00;-1,4,-1,138,-3382,0.00;4,5,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,6,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,7,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,8,-1,5550,4400,0.00;-1,9,-1,-1970,-2666,0.00;4,10,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,11,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,12,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,13,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,14,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,15,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,16,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,17,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,18,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,19,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,20,-1,5550,4400,0.00;-1,21,-1,401,-965,0.00;4,22,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,23,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,24,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,25,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,26,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,27,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,28,-1,5550,4400,0.00;4,29,-1,5550,4400,0.00;:-1970,-2666,0,6.08,A,Dead;"

data.2.test <- list(x1,x2)
```

Each string has 3 main parts seperated by ":".

Part 1: a simple string.

Part 2: 26 chunks separated by ";" which are separated into values by ",".

Part 3: 1 chunk whose values are separated by "," - the length of this part varies.

I have a script that splits this all apart and joins it together but takes about 45 minutes to compute. I need to achieve this significantly quicker. The desire outcome is two dataframes.

1. Data.frame 1 consists of Part 2, with each chunk as a new row and each value in a new column. Part 1 will be added to each row as an 'id'.
2. Data.frame 2 consists of Part 3, with each value in a new column. Part 1 will be added to each row as an 'id'.

Current solution via functions:

```
    Unpack.1.Frame.of.Ball <- function(df){

     ball.parts <- unlist(strsplit(unlist(df),","))
     return(data.frame(team_HA = 10, 
                        TrackID = 50, 
                        JerseyNo = NA, 
                        x = as.numeric(as.character(ball.parts[1])), 
                        y = as.numeric(as.character(ball.parts[2])), 
                        z = as.numeric(as.character(ball.parts[3])),
                        speed = as.numeric(as.character(ball.parts[4])),
                        Ball.Ownership = ifelse(gsub(";","",ball.parts[5])=="A",0,1),
                        Ball.InPlay = ifelse(gsub(";","",ball.parts[6])=="Dead",0,1),
                        Ball.Contact.Info1 = ifelse(length(ball.parts[7])>0,ball.parts[7],NA),
                        Ball.Contact.Info2 = ifelse(length(ball.parts[8])>0,ball.parts[8],NA)))  
}


    Unpack.1.Player.of.Tracking <- function(r){
    return(data.frame(team_HA = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(strsplit(unlist(r),","))[1])), 
                       TrackID = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(strsplit(unlist(r),","))[2])), 
                       JerseyNo = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(strsplit(unlist(r),","))[3])),
                       x = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(strsplit(unlist(r),","))[4])), 
                       y = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(strsplit(unlist(r),","))[5])),
                       speed = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(strsplit(unlist(r),","))[6])),
                       z = 10))
}

    Unpack.1.Frame.of.Players <- function(df){

    unpack.catch <- unlist(strsplit(df, ";")) %>% 
    split(1:length(.)) %>% 
    purrr::map(Unpack.1.Player.of.Tracking) %>% 
    dplyr::bind_rows() 

    return(unpack.catch)
}

    Unpack.1.Frame.of.Time <- function(frame.to.process){

      Parsing.Counter <<- 1
      temp.parts <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(frame.to.process), ":", fixed = FALSE, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE))

      people.temp <- Unpack.1.Frame.of.Players(temp.parts[2])
      ball.temp <- Unpack.1.Frame.of.Ball(temp.parts[3])

      people.temp$Ball.Ownership <- ball.temp$Ball.Ownership
      people.temp$Ball.InPlay <- ball.temp$Ball.InPlay
      people.temp$Ball.Contact.Info1 <- ball.temp$Ball.Contact.Info1
      people.temp$Ball.Contact.Info2 <- ball.temp$Ball.Contact.Info2

      frame.temp <- bind_rows(people.temp, ball.temp)

      frame.temp$frameID <- temp.parts[1]

      if((Parsing.Counter/250)%%1==0){cat(".")}else{}
      Parsing.Counter <<- Parsing.Counter + 1

      return(frame.temp)

}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what the output should look like and what you have tried already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
newdat = data.2.test%>%
            unlist()%>%
            read.table(text = .,sep = ':')%>%
            as.matrix()%>%
            gsub(';','\n',.)%>%
            data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat1 = newdat[-3]%>%
             group_by(V1)%>%
             mutate(V2=list(read.csv(text=V2,header = F,stringsAsFactors = F)))%>%
             unnest()

dat2 = newdat[-2]%>%
         group_by(V1)%>%
         mutate(V3=list(read.csv(text=V3,header = F,stringsAsFactors = F)))%>%
         unnest()

dat1
A tibble: 58 x 7
# Groups:   V1 [2]
   V1        V11    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
   <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 1614689    -1     1    -1  -826 -3484     0
 2 1614689    -1     2    -1  -311 -3450     0
 3 1614689    -1     3    -1 -3732  -708     0
 4 1614689    -1     4    -1   137 -3387     0
 5 1614689     4     5    -1  5550  4400     0
 6 1614689     4     6    -1  5550  4400     0
 7 1614689     4     7    -1  5550  4400     0
 8 1614689     4     8    -1  5550  4400     0
 9 1614689    -1     9    -1 -1971 -2660     0
10 1614689     4    10    -1  5550  4400     0
# ... with 48 more rows

dat2
# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   V1 [2]
  V1        V11    V2    V3    V4 V5    V6   
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 1614689 -1971 -2660     0  6.08 A     Dead 
2 1614690 -1970 -2666     0  6.08 A     Dead
```

Comment: Thanks Onyambu, this is a huge improvement, however V1 is causing some issues. For example, in Data2 V1 should only appear once but it repeats. and in Data1 it remains a constant but should chnage for each 'unpacking' of V2

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option to map out the strings for dataframe 1

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.2.test %>% 
  map(~gsub("^.*?:|:", "", .x) %>% 
        str_split(., ";") %>% 
        unlist() %>% 
        .[1:(length(.)-2)]) %>% 
   map(~str_split(.x, ",")) %>%
   flatten() %>% 
   reduce(rbind) %>%
   as.data.frame()

head(df1)
#>     V1 V2 V3    V4    V5   V6
#> out -1  1 -1  -826 -3484 0.00
#> X   -1  2 -1  -311 -3450 0.00
#> X.1 -1  3 -1 -3732  -708 0.00
#> X.2 -1  4 -1   137 -3387 0.00
#> X.3  4  5 -1  5550  4400 0.00
#> X.4  4  6 -1  5550  4400 0.00
```

Created on 2018-08-15 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

**EDIT**
Changed the output to exclude part 3.

Comment: row 28 should be in dataset 2 and not df1